# jquery show, hide - display first and have an active selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hide, show, show-hide

Tried my best to remedy this myself but cant find the solution and its 3am, you guys are awesome and I know one of you holds the key!

Im wanting a menu with buttons on the left, displaying content in the center of the screen, the first button must display its content on load and be "selected"

html

```
<div class="content-slide-menu">
<ul class="menu">
   <li id="link1"><a href="#null" data-page="page1">blah blah</a></li>
   <li id="link2"><a href="#null" data-page="page2">twit twoo</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content-slide">
<div id="page1" class="content">
    <h3>blah blah</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh eros, commodo sit amet risus a,   
 bibendum venenatis mi. In sed tempus ante. In ac molestie tortor. Proin convallis, diam facilisis volutpat   
 blandit,</p>
    <div class="dots"><span>...</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="content">
   <h3>twit twoo</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh eros, commodo sit amet risus a, 
 bibendum venenatis mi. In sed tempus ante. In ac molestie tortor. Proin convallis, diam facilisis volutpat 
 blandit,</p>
    <div class="dots"><span>...</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.content-slide-menu {
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    padding:0 10px;
}
.content-slide-menu li {
    list-style-type:none;
}
.content-slide-menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#2b2b2b;
    font-size:135%;
}
.content-slide-menu a:hover {
    color:#3ca3c5;
}
.content-slide {
    float:left;
    width:440px;
    margin-top:65px;
}
.content-slide .content {
    display:none;
}
.content-slide .content h3 {
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.content-slide .content p {
    margin:5px 0;
    font-size:110%;
}
.dots {
    font-size:350%;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.active {
    color:#3ca3c5!important;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var curPage = "";
    $(".menu a").click(function () {
        if (curPage.length) {
            $("#" + curPage).hide();
        }
        curPage = $(this).data("page");
        $("#" + curPage).show();
    })

    $('.menu a').click(function () {
        $('.menu a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNR6H/)

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/veT6z/2/

Comment: Very useful, but to add onto this how would I have two of these on one page...? Had a go myself. 
Fiddle below >>

http://jsfiddle.net/veT6z/13/

Comment: they are not similar.. can you assign similar classes to them

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/veT6z/14/

Comment: Exactly like that, <3 Many thanks. Now to de construct the code and figure out what's going on :P

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu a").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this), $slider = $this.closest('.content-slide-menu');
        $slider.next().children('.content').hide();
        $("#" + $this.data("page")).show();
        $slider.find('a.active').removeClass("active");
        $this.addClass('active');
    });
    $('.content-slide-menu li:first-child a').click()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/veT6z/)

Answer (score 1):

html changes...

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="link1"><a href="#null" data-page="page1" class="active">blah blah</a>

    </li>
    <li id="link2"><a href="#null" data-page="page2">twit twoo</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

jquery changes...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var curPage = "";
    $(".menu a").click(function () {
        if (curPage.length) {
            $("#" + curPage).hide();
        }
        curPage = $(this).data("page");
        $("#" + curPage).show();
    }).filter('.active').click();

    $('.menu a').click(function () {
        $('.menu a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```